# How to convert a normal function into a function inside a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to organize my code I already have by implementing classes and execute methods on classes instantiations. I have put some hours into figuring out how to use classes, but still haven't figured it out. Could someone help me?

This is the original code:

```
def readSignalAcquisitionData(fileName):

    f = open(fileName, 'r')

    # dummy read
    f.readline()

    timeStamps = []
    dataInput = []

    for ln in f:
        # parse info
        timeStr, dataStr = ln.split(',')
        timeStamps.append(float(timeStr))
        dataInput.append(float(dataStr))

    f.close()

    return timeStamps, dataInput
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
class SignalDataIOUnit:

    def __init__(self, fileName):

        self.fileName = fileName

    def readSignalAcquisitionData(self):

        f = open(self.fileName, 'r')



        self.timeStamps = []
        self.dataInput = []

        for ln in f:
            # parse info
            self.timeStr, self.dataStr = ln.split(',')
            self.timeStamps.append(float(self.timeStr))
            self.dataInput.append(float(self.dataStr))

        f.close()

        return self.timeStamps, self.dataInput
    def writeFilteredData(self, fileName, timeStamps, dataOut):
        pass

fileName="LabsWeek03_inputData.csv"
timeStamps, dataInput = SignalDataIOUnit.readSignalAcquisitionData(fileName)
print(timeStamps)
```

When I try running it through the terminal I get these error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SignalDataEvaluationUnit_OOP.py", line 26, in <module>
    timeStamps, dataInput = SignalDataIOUnit.readSignalAcquisitionData(fileName)
  File "SignalDataEvaluationUnit_OOP.py", line 7, in readSignalAcquisitionData
    f = open(self.fileName, 'r')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileName'
```

Comment: You're not *instantiating* the class. `SignalDataIOUnit(fileName).readSignalAcquisitionData()`…

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was pretty stupid

Comment: @deceze That looks like a really good answer to this question, one that thijs could mask as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @deceze♦ says in comment, you haven't instantiated the class `SignalDataIOUnit`, that's why it doesn't work.

To make it work, you have 2 choices:

1. **Instantiating `SignalDataIOUnit` object and call the method `readSignalAcquisitionData`**:

```
timeStamps, dataInput = SignalDataIOUnit(fileName).readSignalAcquisitionData()
```

2. **Use Python's [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator**:

```
class SignalDataIOUnit:
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName

    @staticmethod
    def readSignalAcquisitionData(fileName):
        ...
```

then just call it as usual

```
timeStamps, dataInput = SignalDataIOUnit.readSignalAcquisitionData(fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should use like this

```
fileName="LabsWeek03_inputData.csv"

timeStamps, dataInput = SignalDataIOUnit(fileName).readSignalAcquisitionData()
print(timeStamps)
```